# Is convention that cursor is "over" a character in normal mode arbitrary?

Tags: vim

This is a general question that arises when observing unnatural editor behavior to someone not entirely familiar with `vim`:

- entering `insert` then exiting immediately changes the cursor position
- deleting and pasting  (incorrectly) a `[ ]word` produces `some[ ][ ]wordand the rest` (whitespace marked as `[ ]` for clarity)

Suppose there is a `vim`-like editor that defines convention that text is always pasted, inserted, added to the left of a cursor position unless instructed otherwise. Of course, it would need to allow having cursor over a newline character (and for example allow to delete it).

Would that make such editor poorly designed (e.g. inconsistent with its own commands and motions)?

In other words is `vim` convention arbitrary or well designed?

Comment: Enter `insert` mode with `a` instead of `i`, and going back with `<ESC>` will leave the cursor in the initial position.  Paste the word with `P` instead of `p`, and you'll get the expected result.  Perhaps you should consider postponing judgement on Vim design until you learn the basics?

Comment: I'm not arguing that vi lacks appropriate commands. I'm asking whether there are non-arbitrary arguments for the existing convention.

Comment: What convention was that again?  If you imagine the cursor being a line between two characters rather than being "on" a character, you can do things to the left and to the right of the cursor with equal ease.

Answer (score 2):

Sato Katsura and Julie Pelletier already cleared your confusion that Vim has plenty of commands and options at your disposal.  I'll argue about some reasons why the insert mode works the way it works.

In a terminal a character is **not** always under the cursor, for example:

- The cursor may be over EOL
- The cursor may be over a new line character, but a new line character is a character that is not displayed in terminals.

In Vim, even in `normal mode` the cursor can be in a position that does not have a character.  To see this behaviour note that <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>i</kbd> perform the same on an empty line.

Another reason to have different ways to enter `insert-mode` is the fact that pattern search moves the cursor from the current cursor position to the beginning of the match.  Since you can move the cursor over the length of the match you want the insert command to enter insert mode before the match.

Also note that typing <kbd>/</kbd> in `normal-mode` moves the cursor temporarily one character forward, this allows to search repeatedly for new matches of the same pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your confusion but there are very strict instructions in `vi` which `vim` extends:

```
i: insert text before the cursor
I: insert text at the beginning of the line
a: append text after the cursor
A: append text at the end of the line
p: paste the buffer after the cursor
P: paste the buffer before the cursor
```

And the list goes on and on.